# Error message when no search result

Tags: python

I've made a small program that searches the titles of the NYT bestseller list from 1975 -> Today. It works perfectly, but I'm trying to add a message to the word they search for is not find. In the script below the user will just get a blank line if there is no result. I can't figure out how to do this.

On the sixth line from the bottom I've tried to add this code:

```
if title(s) == None:
    print "Sorry, your search gave no results."
```

but that doesn't work. What condition can I set to make the program print an error message if no results?

Here's a sample of the input file:

```
1876    Gore Vidal  Random House    4/11/1976   Fiction
23337   Stephen King    Scribner    11/27/2011  Fiction
1st to Die  James Patterson Little, Brown   3/25/2001   Fiction
2nd Chance  James Patterson Little, Brown   3/24/2002   Fiction
3rd Degree  James Patterson Little, Brown   3/21/2004   Fiction
4th of July James Patterson Little, Brown   5/22/2005   Fiction
```

The program:

```
def title(s):
    f = open("bestsellers.txt", 'r')
    for line in f:
        list = line.split("\t")
        title = list[0]
        author = list[1]
        date = list[3]
        joinList = "".join(title)
        cleanList = joinList.lower()
        if s in cleanList:
            print "   %s, by %s (%s)" % (title, author, date)
    return

while True:
    print "\n"
    print "What would you like to do?"
    print "1: Search for title"
    print "Q: Quit"
    choice = raw_input(">")

    if choice == "q":
        print "Thank you come again"
        break

    elif choice == "1":
        while True:
            s_input = raw_input("Enter a title (or part of a title): ")
            s = s_input.lower()
            title(s)
            break

    else:
        print "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n"
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def title(s):
  f = open("bestsellers.txt", 'r')
  count = 0
  for line in f:
    list = line.split("\t")
    title = list[0]
    author = list[1]
    date = list[3]
    joinList = "".join(title)
    cleanList = joinList.lower()
    if s in cleanList:
        count = 1
        print "   %s, by %s (%s)" % (title, author, date)
  if count == 0:
    print "Sorry, your search gave no results."
return
```